# Polymer fire on-tap with enter

Tags: javascript, html, button, polymer, enter

I am beginner on Polymer. I think that it is a easy Problem but i could not find out how can i implement this on my application.

I have a button on HTML like:

```
<paper-button class="button" id="button-wide" raised affirmative on-tap="{{onClick}}">
```

and in javascript i have function like:

```
Polymer('dialog', {
        onClick: function() {
            ......
            ......
        }}
```

And i want fire this button with enter key on keyboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
Polymer('dialog', {
    onClick: function () {
        // etc..
    },
    onKeyDown: function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13 || e.keyCode === 13) {
            this.onClick();
        }
    },
    attached: function () {
        this.onKeyDown = this.onKeyDown.bind(this);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    },
    detached: function () {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    }
});
```

where attached and detached are [lifecycle methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods) of the element.